# Object distorted in object and pose mode but looks fine in edit mode

Tags: transforms, pose-mode, object-mode

[image: stick1]

[image: stick2]

I've already reset the transforms with alt+s alt+r and alt+g in pose/object mode, there is only the armature modifier. I've tried adding some extra loops around the middle of his stomach but he still just looks like he ate a really sour candy. I'm kind of a blender noob so any help will be appreciated. :D

[image]

Comment: Please don't use external servers for Blend files. You can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to add a link to the file.

Comment: My bad, fixed it

Comment: You haven't added a link to it though so we can't see it!

Comment: Oh lol, you're right I didn't add the link

Comment: Hmm.. I think someone with more knowledge of armatures than me is going to have to answer that one! It's not just the stomach which is being turned inside out. - Look at the arms from the side in Object and Edit mode! The only thing I found (which made no difference) is that you had over 4000 overlapping vertices on the object but merging them makes no difference.

Comment: Dang, thanks anyway. Maybe I'll just remake him or something, he's only a stick man after all :D

Comment: He's got a BIG sword for just a stick man! :^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The armature distorts because you have given *IK* constraints to your hands and IK bones will stick to their controller as soon as you'll switch to *Pose* mode, to avoid that you should make your IK bones already stick to their controllers in *Edit* mode. Also I'm not sure why you give the *IK* to the hands as it would be more logical to give them to the forearms, just parent the hands to the controllers. Make sure that the IK *Pole Angle* value is good. At last don't forget to bend the elbows and knees a bit so that Blender knows in which direction they are supposed to bend. At the end you should have a setup like that:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description! I'm going to do exactly this and I'll mark your answer as the answer if it works

Comment: DOn't hesitate to ask if you don't understand something   ;)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, I think when I remove the hand bone it becomes not enough bones and when I move the IK bone the other bones don't bend. It's probably because I suck lmao. It did make it not stretch my object though

Comment: please share your new file

Comment: Hey, I fully removed the IK, I think it's easier to animate with just the normal bones maybe [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=KeaBlMYY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/KeaBlMYY/) This is my new file

Comment: mmh I don't think so but if you feel more comfortable this way...   ;)

Answer (score 0):

After deleting half of the object and mirror modifying it to recreate it, then recreating the entire thing from scratch and having the same problem I figured it out..

I turned off deform on the 2 inner-most arm bones, they don't really need to deform anyway.

[image]